# Postgres: How to query `where id in (some_other_col_json_array)`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two particular tables I'm working with. `users` and `tags`. The `users` table has a `tags` column of type `json` which stores references of id's mapping to the `tags` table. Eg:

```
users
  .id        // Int
  .tags      // JSON array. Eg [1, 5, 9, 22, 64]

tags
  .id        // Int
  .tag_name  // String
```

I'd like to get all the tags for a given user id. Something to the likes of the following pseudo postgres query:

```
select u.id, 
       u.first_name, 
       u.last_name, 
       array(select pt.tag_name from profile_tags pt where pt.id in (u.tags)) as p_tags
from users u
where u.id=$1
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I'd love some help getting this right.

Comment: Do proper normalization and your problem will go away.

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to normalize the JSON by unnesting the array, then you can join and aggregate:

```
select u.id, 
       u.first_name, 
       u.last_name, 
       array_agg(t.tag_name) 
from users u
  cross join lateral json_array_elements(u.tags) as ut(id)
  join tags t on t.id = ut.id::int
group by u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name;
```

---

If you do this a lot, storing the tag references in a properly normalized model will most probably be more efficient. Even storing the tag IDs in an integer array column would already be easier and more efficient.